# SQL select from unlerated tables as well as related tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I'm getting an error (`#1054 - Unknown column 'post.make_id' in 'on clause'` ) with the following query :

```
SELECT `post`.* 
FROM `post`, 
`city` `postCity`
LEFT JOIN `make` ON `post`.`make_id` = `make`.`id`
```

If I remove `` city` `postCity ``, no error.
Is there any way for me to query the `city` table even though it's not related to the `post` table and at the same time do the left join with other tables ?

Comment: What is `postCity` ? A column?

Comment: Don't mix implicit (comma separated) joins and explicit joins.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN is evaluated before the implicit join. The ON condition has no access to the post table.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is the mixing of commas with proper `JOIN` syntax.

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM post p CROSS JOIN
     city c LEFT JOIN
     make m
     ON p.make_id = m.id;
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  This doesn't look particularly useful, but it might fix your syntax error.

Comment: It did thanks a lot !
What I'm trying to do is calculate the distance between the post creator and the logged in user using the city's latitude and longitude.